# Keyboard not working after BIOS. What should I do? (Клавиатура не работает после биоса. Что мне делать?)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, bios, mouse, ps2

After installing 2 programs and rebooting in Windows, my keyboard and mouse do not work.
I tried many settings in the BIOS (Version Ami 2.5x-2.6x). I searched for a long time on the Internet - did not help.
USB keyboards don't work in BIOS. With a USB mouse, the same problem: it says "the driver has been successfully installed", but there is no reaction from the device.
I put a jumper in the motherboard to close the contacts - nothing
has changed. I took out the battery (BIOS) for a certain time and then put it in - nothing.
Keyboard and mouse (PS/2) are fine. On the keyboard ps/2 Num lock is on, after starting
Windows - it is on but does not react. Before starting, I can press Num Lock, Caps Lock, Scroll
Lock - everything responds and changes, and after starting Windows does not react.
I'll tell you what happens: I turn on the PC, after I hear 1 squeak from the BIOS (everything is in order), then 3 lights on the keyboard light up, go out, and as soon as the "Starting Windows"
screen appears, the keyboard does not work. In all safe modes the situation is the same.
The BIOS is old and has not been updated.
I'm new to OS reinstallation; I will use this method if all else fails.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are the two programs that you installed?

Comment: And did you try to find updated BIOS?  How old is the computer?

Comment: Not trying, relatively old computer. I think the programs (Reg Organizer and Panda Security) cleaned up what was not needed, probably the system files were affected.

Comment: You say you have a PS/2 keyboard and mouse also. Can you use them and remove the two software and see if that helps? But if they did some damage, it's *possible* a Windows repair will be needed.

Comment: I've tried disabling USB mouse and keyboard support in the BIOS, but that didn't help. As I said, the bios is old, you can't do much there. Thanks for the advice, i try again, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to restore the system. While the topic is closed. Thanks everyone)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).